# Prevent instantiation of a class from a library

Tags: java

I am developing an application which depends on a certain library. I do not have any control over the library code.

I have extended a class from this library in my application. I want my application to only be able to create instances of this extended class, not the parent class.

Is there a way to prevent object creation of parent class?

Comment: What are the options you have researched?

Comment: I guess you might be able to achieve something with a custom classloader, but I'd also guess there might be an easier way. How does your application create instances? If it's not dynamic, just don't use the parent class. If it is dynamc, maybe put an instanceof check after the creation?

Comment: do you need to prevent instantiation of a library class only in your application code or in the library code as well?

Comment: Only in application code. I need to ensure that other developers don't instantiate objects from parent class

Comment: Than the only option is to create a Facade for third party library and force other developers to use it. There is no language feature to forbid class instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way in which you can restrict the creation of parent instance, if you will see the architecture the "initializer" make sure that the instance is created and at the same time the allocate the heap space.

At the end the memory has to be allocated and instances has to be created.